# Python: looking for specific Index in xml file and return an xml again

Tags: python, xml

I'm stuck, if anyone could help me i'll appreciate it.

I have a xml file, from that file i must pull out the constant parameters and Index I'm looking for. In the end must created me a new xml file . I stuck at Index i'm looking for, because that Index must be writen in the group where it's.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('master.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

variables = root.iter('Variable')
records = root.iter('Record')
arrays = root.iter('Array')
s = input('input number of Index and add quotes befor and after: ')
i = int(s, 16)

for MagicNumber in root.findall('MagicNumber'):
    print('\n')
for FileInfo in root.find('FileInfo'):
    print FileInfo.tag,':', FileInfo.text
print''
for DeviceInfo in root.find('DeviceInfo'):
    print DeviceInfo.tag,':', DeviceInfo.text
print''
for DummyUsage in root.find('DummyUsage'):
    print DummyUsage.tag,':', DummyUsage.text
print''
for ObjectDictionary in root.find('ObjectDictionary'):
    name=ObjectDictionary.get('name')
    print ObjectDictionary.tag,':', ObjectDictionary.text, name 
    for i in ObjectDictionary.text, name:        
        for node in variables:
            if node.find('./Index').text == str(i):
                print 'variable name: ', node.attrib['name']
            elif node.find('./Index').text != str(i):
                pass
        for node in records:
            if node.find('./Index').text == str(i):
                print 'records name: ', node.attrib['name']
            elif node.find('./Index').text != str(i):
                pass
        for node in arrays:
            if node.find('./Index').text == str(i):
                print 'arrays name: ', node.attrib['name']
            elif node.find('./Index').text != str(i):
                pass
tree.write('output.xml')
```

and this prints me out:

CONSTANT PARAMETRS....

Group :

```
        MandatoryObjects
```

Group :

```
        OptionalObjects
```

Group :

```
        ManufacturerObjects
```

Group :

```
        ParametersObjects
```

If i'm looking for 2000 Index, that inex is in group: OptionalObject, so under that group must be printed only parametrs(variables,records,arrays) of Index 2000 and put me out a new xml file

Hope I was enough understandable.

Comment: I am confused. Whatt is your overall goal? Do you want to split an xml file into smaller xml files?

Comment: first of all i want that Index i'm looking for, print it under the right group. (If it's Index 2000 under OptionalObject, must print me under OptionalObjects with all variables, records and arrays...
I hope you understand me.
after this must put me out an xml file with constant parameters all 4 groups and just Index i'm looking for.